# Google Sheet: how to get value of another cell on the same row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a formula:

1. If I put it in a cell, for example C2, it will return the value in A2
2. I can't simply put `=A2` because column A could be moved to another column

I am trying to use named range to do this. I have created a named range(`teacher_Names`) for A1:A. It is not hard to get the value using app script

```
function getTeacherNameOnTheSameRow(row) {
  let ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let values = ss.getRangeByName('teacher_Names').getValues();
  return values[row-1];
}
```

I can just put `=getTeacherNameOnTheSameRow(Row())` in cells in Column C, and no matter which column I move column A to, it will work.

My question is, is there a way to do this without app script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- The column "A" has the named range of `teacher_Names`.
- You have a Google Apps Script of custom function, and the script works.
- You want to achieve the custom function as the built-in function without using Google Apps Script.
- For example, when you put the built-in function to the row 5 of the column "C", you want to retrieve the value of the row 5 of the column "A" to the column "C".

In this case, how about the following formula?

#### Sample formula:

Please put the following formula to the column "C". By this, the column "A" of the named range `teacher_Names` is retrieved with the same row.

```
=teacher_Names
```

Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- For example, when you put the formula of `=ARRAYFORMULA(teacher_Names)` to the cell "C1", you can see the values of the column "A" to the column "C".
- Also, in this case, even when the column "A" is moved to other column, the values are kept.

Comment: Can't believe it is so simple lol. So I am still a little confused about when the formula will smartly use current cell's info as its parameter. For example, suppose I have another named range `course`, I can do `=teacher_Names&course`, but `TEXTJOIN(' ',teacher_Names,course)` will output the whole range's values into one cell. So why `textjoin` doesn't work here? What kind of formulas work this way?

Comment: @shenkwen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, I would like to recommend to post it as new question. Can you post it as new question by more information? By this, it will help a lot of users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?